# flutter bloc:How to provide a single instance of a cubit for a bottom bar screen and a normal Screen?

Tags: flutter, navigation, bloc, cubit

I have a navigation bottom bar in my app.
I created a custom class for routing that sets up all the logic for navigating to all the screens in the app, but the bottom bar pages are not in this custom class.
I have a problem providing a single instance of a cubit for a bottom bar's screen and a screen in the custom class.
Are there any suggestions?

```
class UserNavScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = 'homepage_screen';

  UserNavScreen();

  @override
  State<UserNavScreen> createState() => _UserNavScreenState();
}

class _UserNavScreenState extends State<UserNavScreen> {
  var _index = 2;

  final _userPages = [
    const UserProfileScreen(),
    const UserNotificationScreen(),
    BlocProvider<MapCubit>(
        create: (context) => MapCubit(
              mapRepositery: MapRepositery(
                mapProvider: MapProvider(),
              ),
              storesRepositery: StoresRepositery(
                storesProvider: StoresProvider(),
              ),
            )..getStoresLocation(),
        child: UserMapScreen()),
    const UserTopTenScreen(),
    const UserHomepageScreen()
  ];

 

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _userPages[_index],
      bottomNavigationBar: _buildNavUser(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildNavUser() {
    return StyleProvider(
      style: StyleNavBottomBar(),
      child: ConvexAppBar(
        style: TabStyle.fixedCircle,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        color: Colors.grey,
        initialActiveIndex: _index,
        activeColor: Colors.green,
        cornerRadius: 16,
        curveSize: 90,
        height: 60,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _index = index;
          });
        },
        elevation: 2,
        items: const [
          TabItem(
            icon: Icons.person,
          ),
          TabItem(
            icon: Icons.notifications,
          ),
          TabItem(icon: Icons.navigation),
          TabItem(
            icon: FontAwesomeIcons.medal,
          ),
          TabItem(
            icon: Icons.home,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


class AppRoute {
  
  Route? onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings routeSettings) {
    switch (routeSettings.name) {
 case StoreMap.routeName:
        final args = routeSettings.arguments as Store;
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => StoreMap(store: args),
        );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try put BlocProvider on top of Scaffold

Answer (score 0):

It seems we have almost identical navigation setup, what I've gone through was to lazily instantiate the cubit inside the routing class, then supply it to the named route using **BlocProvider.value**, after that provide the routing class globally using **RepositoryProvider** as follows:

```
class AppRoute {
  //* This will only get instantiated when used
  late final MapCubit mapCubit = MapCubit(MapRepository(
      mapProvider: MapProvider(), storesProvider: StoresProvider()));

  Route? onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings routeSettings) {
    switch (routeSettings.name) {
      case StoreMap.routeName:
        final args = routeSettings.arguments as Store;
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => BlocProvider.value(
            value: mapCubit,
            child: StoreMap(store: args),
          ),
        );
    }
  }

  void dispose() {
    mapCubit.close();
  }
}
```

Now in *main.dart*

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    App(),
  );
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<App> createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  @override
  void dispose() {
    context.read<AppRoute>().dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RepositoryProvider(
      create: (context) => AppRoute(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        // some traditional code & boilerplate....
        onGenerateRoute: context.read<AppRoute>().onGenerateRoute,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now we can access the cubit anywhere, and specifically from *UserNavScreen* where we provide it further to the required page:

```
class UserNavScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = 'homepage_screen';

  const UserNavScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<UserNavScreen> createState() => _UserNavScreenState();
}

class _UserNavScreenState extends State<UserNavScreen> {
  var _index = 2;
  late final AppRoute _appRoute;
  late final List<Widget> _userPages;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _appRoute = context.read<AppRoute>();
    _userPages = [
      const UserProfileScreen(),
      const UserNotificationScreen(),
      //* Here we're accessing the same cubit instance that named routes will access.
      BlocProvider<MapCubit>.value(
        value: _appRoute.mapCubit..getStoresLocation(),
        child: const UserMapScreen(),
      ),
      const UserTopTenScreen(),
      const UserHomepageScreen(),
    ];
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _userPages[_index],
      bottomNavigationBar: _buildNavUser(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildNavUser() {
    return StyleProvider(
      style: StyleNavBottomBar(),
      child: ConvexAppBar(
        style: TabStyle.fixedCircle,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        color: Colors.grey,
        initialActiveIndex: _index,
        activeColor: Colors.green,
        cornerRadius: 16,
        curveSize: 90,
        height: 60,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _index = index;
          });
        },
        elevation: 2,
        items: const [
          TabItem(
            icon: Icons.person,
          ),
          TabItem(
            icon: Icons.notifications,
          ),
          TabItem(icon: Icons.navigation),
          TabItem(
            icon: FontAwesomeIcons.medal,
          ),
          TabItem(
            icon: Icons.home,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

PS: Notice the dispose method inside the AppRoute class (I prefer calling it AppRouter btw), this method is to dispose the cubit when we're sure it will never be used again, in our case it's where it got first instantiated (inside UserNavScreen), and that is because it's our responsibility to close a cubit/bloc that was provided by *BlocProvider.value* .